# Ошибка git в терминале Vscode Please use a personal access token instead при вводе команды push

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push

Ошибка при команде push (VS Code терминал):

PS C:\Users`````v\dev\gms> git push fatal: The current branch feature/card has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin feature/card
PS C:\Users\Za``````````ms> git push --set-upstream origin feature/card remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://github.com/Sl````/``s.git/'

Я так понял из-за необходимости использован я токена, но я ранее вводил команду: git remote add origin http://LOGIN:TOKEN@github.com/S````/``s.git. Она вроде должна подключить с использованием токена.

Comment: Я может сходу и не понял проблемы. Но исходя из сообщения, похоже, что вам рекомендуют использовать 
`--set-upstream` при пуше

Comment: Да, я его использовал, но вышла новая ошибка: Please use a personal access token instead. Я нашел инфо, что нужно использовать команду ( в связи с необходимостью с августа использовать токен при авторизации git): git remote add origin http://LOGIN:TOKEN@github.com/S````/``s.git, но она не помогла, ошибка осталась.

Answer (score 0):

Решил, надо еще в винду в учетную запись добавить токен вместо пароля.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]